# How to create buckets for 'count of sessions' in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I want to recreate this view from google analytics in data studio:

[image: View from Google Analytics]

In GDS it shows every 'count of sessions' independently and I want to create buckets like in the picture above. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

This code is big and if you are not a programmer this can be scary at first, so I will try to walk you through the logic and then give you the code.

First of all, you need to create a NEW FIELD where you can write a code.

Follow [this tutorial](https://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/10-calculated-fields-data-studio/) until you get to this point:

[image: DataStudio New Field Screen]

Great! Now you're all set to start codding!

The Logic:

- For numbers 1-8 you do nothing,
- For numbers 9-14 you need to know if `Count of Sessions` is bigger than 8 AND smaller than 15. The same logic goes for the other ones.
- For the "200+" field you need a code that gets any value bigger than 200 and returns a TEXT "200+"

IMPORTANT:

In DataStudio `Count of Sessions` is a TEXT field. If you want to use it as a number you have to change it in the configurations. I assumed you didn't do it, so I will use this code to tell DataStudio to look at your `Count of Sessions` but read it as a number. The code is:

```
CAST(Count of Sessions AS NUMBER )
```

If in your DataStudio Project `Count of Sessions` IS a NUMBER field, you will need to change all places where you see `CAST(Count of Sessions AS NUMBER )` for only `Count of Sessions`.

A simple code that only tells if a number is bigger than 8 works like that:

```
IF(CAST(Count of Sessions AS NUMBER ) > 8, "9+", Count of Sessions)
```

I suggest you search for how this IF statement works.

Now, using everything we talked about, the complete code for what you want is:

```
IF(CAST(Count of Sessions AS NUMBER ) > 8, IF(CAST(Count of Sessions AS NUMBER ) < 15, "9-14", IF(CAST(Count of Sessions AS NUMBER ) < 26, "15-25", IF(CAST(Count of Sessions AS NUMBER ) < 51, "26-50", IF(CAST(Count of Sessions AS NUMBER ) < 101, "51-100", IF(CAST(Count of Sessions AS NUMBER ) < 201, "101-200", "201+" ) ) ) ) ), Count of Sessions )
```

It might look a bit confusing, but it works! Hope this helps you and that you got a feeling of why it works.